# How would I access the values of the coordinates through a NodeJS MongoDB query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("607ce141dfc52641ea652fb2"), 
    "Timestamp" : ISODate("2020-11-18T02:38:22.000+0000"), 
    "Class" : "Class A", 
    "MMSI" : 219022256, 
    "MsgType" : "position_report", 
    "Position" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            54.572058, 
            11.928778
        ]
    }, 
    "Status" : "Under way using engine", 
    "RoT" : 0.0, 
    "SoG" : 0.0, 
    "CoG" : 264.6, 
    "Heading" : 207
}
```

Here is my query: const ships = await ais
.aggregate(
[{ $match: { MMSI: 219022256 } }, { $sort: { Timestamp: -1 } }],
{
allowDiskUse: true,
}
)
.project({ _id: 0 })
.limit(1)
.toArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering the returned values you have an Array of objects (JSON objects) at your disposal, so you would be able to use the informations of each object like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < Ships.length; i++){
   console.log(Ships[i]["Position"]["Coordinates"]);
   let myCoordinates = Ships[i]["Position"]["Coordinates"];
   let lat = myCoordinates[0];
   let lon = myCoordinates[1];
   // Use the coordinates
}
```

Cheers!